# Python: passing a library function from command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

$python example.py --function cos(x)

```
x = [...]

def foo(f, x):
    return f(x)
```

Is there a smart way I can pass any function (let's say any mathematic functions defined in numpy for simplicity) from the command line so that it will produce the same result that would produce the following piece of code:

```
foo(lambda t: numpy.cos(t), x)
```

Comment: You're going to run into parsing problems almost immediately; [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) may be of interest to you. To get the values in from the command line, just use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have specified *python2.7*, you can use the `import_module` function from the backported [importlib](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html) module.

```
>>> np = importlib.import_module('numpy')
>>> cos = getattr(np, 'cos')
>>> cos
<ufunc 'cos'>
>>> cos(3.14159)
-0.99999999999647926
```

You would need to parse the command line options (using `argparse` as @HenryKeiter suggests in the comments), then split the function from the module string, import the module and use getattr to access the function.

```
>>> def loadfunc(dotted_string):
...     params = dotted_string.split('.')
...     func = params[-1]
...     module = '.'.join(params[:-1])
...     mod =  importlib.import_module(module)
...     return getattr(mod, func)
...
>>> loadfunc('os.getcwd')
<built-in function getcwd>
>>> loadfunc('numpy.sin')
<ufunc 'sin'>
>>> f = loadfunc('numpy.cos')
>>> f(3.14159)
-0.99999999999647926
```

Note this doesn't load functions from the global namespace, and you might want to add some error checking.

**EDIT**

There is also no need for the lambda function in this line

```
foo(lambda t: numpy.cos(t), x)
```

You can just pass numpy.cos directly without evaluating it

```
foo(numpy.cos, x)
```